# Algolia: can I set expiry time for records?

Tags: algolia

I'm using Algolia to index my docs.  I don't want the number of records to grow unboundedly.  Is there a way to set an expiry time for each record so they're automatically deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve that would be to add an attribute to your record with the expiry dates and run a script regularly to delete the data. For instance. I would use an int so you can use numeric filters (see: https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/#numeric-filters)

```
{
  name: "test",
  expire: 20171201
}
```